# How to create excutables with +RTS -N for concurrency in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to create a Windows executable.

My program uses the async library for concurrently downloading files from a website.

I remember in order to run concurrent programs, I need to provide the appropriate flags, both compile time and runtime.

For console program launching, i can simply do:

`./myprogram.exe +RTS -N4` for example.

But what should I do if `myprogram.exe` is to be launched by clicking it?

Comment: Note that concurrent downloads are likely to be limited by the your bandwidth or by the server's configuration long before you need multiple OS threads to keep up.  GHC's green threads are fully capable of running concurrently even without multiple OS threads.

Comment: @Carl I plan to use `mapConcurrently` from `Control.Concurrent.Async`. It does use the green threads right?

Comment: Yes, `mapConcurrently` does use all of GHC's standard tools.

Comment: If you control the program and can rebuild it, Daniel Wagner’s recommendation to use `-with-rtsopts` is right. For other cases, you can create a shortcut (`.lnk`) and specify the RTS options (or other flags and environment variables) in the shortcut’s command field. I’ve sometimes made multiple shortcuts to the same executable with different options for convenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [user's guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/runtime_control.html) says:

> There are four ways to set RTS options:
>
> - on the command line between +RTS ... -RTS, when running the program (Setting RTS options on the command line)
> - at compile-time, using -with-rtsopts=⟨opts⟩ (Setting RTS options at compile time)
> - with the environment variable GHCRTS (Setting RTS options with the GHCRTS environment variable)
> - by overriding “hooks” in the runtime system (“Hooks” to change RTS behaviour)

The second bullet gets you where you want to go.

Additionally, many of the RTS options are programmatically controllable, in case you want to do some computation before choosing the value -- say, checking how many physical CPUs there are. For `-N` specifically, there is [`setNumCapabilities`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v:setNumCapabilities).